# Neighboors of some Set S include the elements of S?

Tags: graph-theory

Currently going through an [ocw-course](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/index.htm).

I have come across something, I am not sure if I understood correctly.

On page 134 of the reading in Definition 5.2.4, it states the following:

> In any
> graph, the set N(S), of neighbors of some set, S, of vertices is the set of all vertices
> adjacent to some vertex in S .

Which I interpreted as every vertex that is not in the set of S but which makes an edge with an element in S.

The text then goes on to put the words in a more mathematical form.

> N(S) = {r|{s,r} is an edge for some s element S}

But this now looks to me as if any vertex which is in S and has an edge with a vertex in S  is also part of N(S).

Which one is it, are the vertices in S excluded from N(S) or does the neighborhood also consists of the vertices which are part of S?

Example

> G=(V,E)
> V={V1,V2,V3,V4}
> E={{V1,V2},{V2,V3},{V2,V4}}
>
> S={V1,V2}
>
> Is N(S)={V1,V2,V3,V4} or is N(S)={V3,V4}

Thanks.

Comment: I would say that both definitions you've given actually agree. The set $N(S)$ can contain vertices in $S$.

Comment: Thanks, yeah it slowly becomes clear to me, I think I just tripped over the "neighbors" somehow.

So the correct answer to the example would be N(S)={V1,V2,V3,V4}

Comment: The thing to keep straight here, I think, is that a node specifically is not its own neighbour (unless you have a looping edge). So $\{s\}$ and $N(\{s\})$ are usually disjoint for a vertex $s$. However, if $r$ and $s$ are neighbours, then both $r$ and $s$ are contained in $N(\{r, s\})$.